# Unix shell scripting which matches a pattern from one file and count the no of occurences and append that line by some description

Tags: unix

I have this data:

```
vi reason.txt //normal text file which contains some data
    Disk space
    File space

vi pattern.txt    //text file which contains duplicate lines
    Disk space
    File space
    File space
```

I want the output as:

```
    Disk space (count of disk space)-->Informal term for data storage.
    File space (count of file space)-->File storage
```

I want the count of disk space and file space where Informal term for data storage & File storage are the descriptions.

output should be like this

```
    Disk space(1)-->Informal term for data storage.
    File space(2)-->File storage.
```

> *[Here I must past what I tried to achieve my goal, and why it failed (error messages, unexpected behavior) otherwise people could believe I want them to do my job on my stand...]*

Comment: can you define it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
echo Disk space \(`grep Disk pattern.txt | wc -l`\)--\>Informal term for data storage.
echo File space \(`grep File pattern.txt | wc -l`\)--\>File storage
```

Comment: Script has to read the file line by line then it has to print the mentioned output as  above

Comment: We have to consider reason.txt as well

Comment: @BhargavMB: Do you meant that you object to this method because it scans the file twice? Do you prefer any particular language, like bash or Perl?

Comment: asssume this as an example

vi a.txt
Programming Languages
Object Oriented


vi b.txt
Programming Languages
Programming Languages
Programming Languages
Object Oriented
Object Oriented


output~~~~

Programming Languages(3)-->A set of coventions in which the instructions are written
Object Oriented(2)-->Enables a system to be modelled as a set of objects


I've written the script for this :

vi 1.sh
grep -f $1 $2|uniq -c 
//This will count the no of occurences .I need those description to be printed as shown in the above output. @Beta

Comment: Maybe we have a language barrier. In my Answer, I described two commands (which can be put into a shell script) which will produce the output you requested. You objected to my solution, but I do not understand your objection. You now give a different example with different parameters, and a script which solves part of the problem. I wish to help, but this problem is a moving target.